# How to send notification to the super admin in the Back end From Front end in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Hi i am working on a Joomla Project in which i have to send notification to the super admin in the back end.

Whenever a user in the multiples of 1,00,000 registers with the website a notification should be automatically sent to the super admin in the back end of Joomla.

The notification should mention the total number of users in the website and the information of the user which has achieved the milestone of being 1,00,000 user.

i am able to find out the number of users by using MySQL COUNT but how to send notification?

is there any way to send notification in Joomla from front end to back end or should i save the results in database and then show the result to the super admin only when the 1,00,000 users are registered?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Joomla [plug-in](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin) that catches a relevant [Event](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) and then [sends an email](http://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions) to members of the Administrator/Super User groups. They are not that complicated and [the development process is documented](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla).

As there isn't a specific event for user registration, I would probably suggest you start with the [`onUserBeforeSave`](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserBeforeSave) or [`onUserAfterSave`](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserAfterSave) events.